# Can't get range slider to move along with audio while it's playing

Tags: jquery, input, slider, html5-audio, audio-player

I have an mp3 player I built with JQuery.  I followed a tutorial which was great but the player didn't have scrubbing, just a progress bar that you couldn't alter.  In researching, I found some code for scrubbing which works fine:

```
$("#seek").bind("change", function() {
    audio.currentTime = $(this).val();
    $("#seek").attr("max", audio.duration);     
});
```

That's all fine.  But the slider does not move along with the audio as it plays.  I've tried lots of different code from different places but nothing seems to work.  My latest attempt looks like this (it's the last line that doesn't work):

```
function showDuration(){
    $(audio).bind('timeupdate', function(){
        //Get hours and minutes
        var s = parseInt(audio.currentTime % 60);
        var m = parseInt((audio.currentTime / 60) % 60);
        //Add 0 if seconds less than 10
        if (s < 10) {
            s = '0' + s;
        }
        $('#duration').html(m + '.' + s);   
        var valueSlider = 0;
        if (audio.currentTime > 0) {
            valueSlider = Math.floor((100 / audio.duration) *     
            audio.currentTime);
        }
        $('#seek').html('value',valueSlider);
    });
}
```

All of that is just for the duration display except the last line.  That I added to try to change the value of the slider to match the audio duration.  I've also tried:

```
$('#seek').attr('value',valueSlider);
```

My HTML for the slider looks like this:

```
 <div id="tracker">
        <input id="seek" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0"/>
        <span id="duration"></span>
     </div>
```

I thought maybe the values I was putting in for min, max, value were preventing the JQuery from changing it dynamically, but when I put nothing in it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use jQuery's `val()` as a setter to change the value, so change this

```
$('#seek').html('value',valueSlider);
```

to

```
$('#seek').val(valueSlider);
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks so much.

Comment: The slider doesn't stay when I slide it